# Detect that hardware "Back" button is pressed

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I need your help. I create input text field via `native.newTextField()` also I add event listener on 'key' for detect hardware "Back" button pressed. When I edit input text field and press Back button I didn't catch this event. How can I solve this? Maybe something check open or not hardware keyboard.

Thanks.

Comment: provide your code

Comment: How are you adding the 'key' listener? Please post you code.

Answer (score 0):

It will never receive it.Check the [doc](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/key/index.html) of Corona SDK. They say **"Key events will not be received if a native object such as a TextField, TextBox, or WebView handles them."**